Help Proving an Inequality Involving $n \sqrt{2}$
I'm trying to prove the following inequality and would appreciate some help:
$$
n \sqrt{2}>\lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor+\frac{1}{2 n \sqrt{2}}
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ (i.e., $n$ is a positive integer).
Here's what I've done so far:

I've expressed $n \sqrt{2}$ as $\lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor+\{n \sqrt{2}\}$, where $\{n \sqrt{2}\}$ is the fractional part of $n \sqrt{2}$.
The inequality then reduces to proving that:

$$
\{n \sqrt{2}\}>\frac{1}{2 n \sqrt{2}}
$$

I've considered the bounds of the fractional part $\{n \sqrt{2}\}$, which lies in $[0,1)$, but I'm struggling to rigorously prove this strict inequality.

If anyone could provide insights or a detailed solution, I'd be very grateful!
Thank you in advance for your help.

Have you considered inducting on $n$?

give a name $m = \lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor  < n \sqrt 2.$  Then $m^2 - 2 n^2 <0 $ is an integer with $m^2 - 2 n^2 \leq -1$ so $(m - n \sqrt 2)( m + n \sqrt 2) \leq -1,$  then  $(-m + n \sqrt 2)( m + n \sqrt 2) \geq 1.$

You know that $2n^2$ is not the square of an integer, so $\left(\lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor\right)^2 \le 2n^2-1$.
Meanwhile $\left(n \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2 n \sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = 2n^2-1+\frac{1}{8n^2} \gt 2n^2-1$.
So $n \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2 n \sqrt{2}} > \lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor$ and thus $n \sqrt{2} > \lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor +\frac{1}{2 n \sqrt{2}}$.

The tighter cases when $2n^2-1$ is a square are $n=1, 5, 29, 169, 985, \ldots$ related to the continued fraction approximations to $\sqrt{2}$
